# Android app FC when converting to Integer

Tags: android, forceclose, parseint

I have an android app which has a few edittext boxes. I need to convert one of the edittext box value to use for calculation. I have the following code:

```
final EditText taken = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String no=taken.getText().toString();
int no2=Integer.parseInt(no);
```

For some reason, everytime I run the app on my phone (JB 4.2.2), it FC but if i comment out the code my app works just fine. Any idea what am I missing?

> ```
> <EditText
>     android:id="@+id/editText1"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
>     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
>     android:ems="10"
>     android:inputType="number" >
>     <requestFocus />
> </EditText>
> ```

Comment: What's the logcat output?  Is there an exception?

Comment: Look in logcat, it will tell you *exactly* why

Comment: I am using Eclipse and debugging directly on my phone. How would I verify it?

Comment: Sounds like a Number Format Exception, look in the logcat view of eclipse when running in debug mode

Comment: `Integer.parseInt()` is going to throw an exception when the `String` doesn't represent an integer.

Comment: I setup the EditText to only input numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, post the output of the logcat.
Probably, this happens when in your EditText you don't have a number (other symbol).
You can try something like this:

```
        int no2;
        try {
            no2=Integer.parseInt(no);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            no2=0; //default value. Ya can trigger some event here
        }
```

Comment: I was doing the check before I entered something in the textbox! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use try...catch exception for handle errors.